# How can pass a data of a node's field to entityform field

Tags: forms, tokens, entities

I have a field named "code". This hidden field stores some alfa_numeric values.

Nodes with using this data field have an entityform type as a block in page.

How can I pass node's data values to entityforms data field as prepopulated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hook_form_alter in a custom module and pass the node field value to the value of the form item eg :

```
<?php
  function mymodule_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    // dpm($form);
    $node = node_load(arg(1));
    $form['field_code']['#value'] = $node->my_field[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  }
?>
```

Things you need to know are:

The ID of the entity form for `FORM_ID`, you can get this using [Get form ID](http://drupal.org/project/get_form_id) module.

What the field you are populating is ? you can install [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module then uncomment the line in the above code to inspect the form.

Where within the node object the field with the data is ? If Devel is installed you can navigate to the node and click on the Devel tab and explore the node there.

If you are using hidden fields then `['#value']` is ok but if it is a textfield then you should use `['#default_value']`.

Also, this is presuming that the form is in a block on the node page, other wise `node_load(arg(1));` will node work.